# How to export only views from a database?

Tags: mysql

I have to export only the views of a database, I tried several combinations with mysqldump but I can not get it to work.

Can the database be exported without the definer?

Comment: If you understand views as images.. You should save the URL of the image..

Answer (score 4):

This should help. The script parses all views in selected database and dumps them to file

```
 mysql -u username INFORMATION_SCHEMA
  --skip-column-names --batch
  -e "select table_name from tables where table_type = 'VIEW'
      and table_schema = 'database'"
  | xargs mysqldump -u username database
  > views.sql
```

In your particular case it would be

```
 mysql -u root INFORMATION_SCHEMA 
   --skip-column-names --batch 
   -e "select table_name from tables 
       where table_type = 'VIEW' and 
             table_schema = 'DATA_BASE_EXAMPLE'" | xargs 
   mysqldump -u root DATA_BASE_EXAMPLE > "C:\Users\USER1\Desktop\Buckup\vistas.sql
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, if I have seen this instruction, but I have problems when using
Would it be correct in this way?for example                                                                      `mysql -u root DATA_BASE_EXAMPLE
  --skip-column-names --batch
  -e "select table_name from tables where table_type = 'VIEW'
      and table_schema = 'DATA_BASE_EXAMPLE'"

  | xargs mysqldump -u root DATA_BASE_EXAMPLE
  > "C:\Users\USER1\Desktop\Buckup\vistas.sql"`

Answer (score 1):

The best way I found to export views avoiding the use of the definer was with a visual tool [DBeaver Community Edition](https://dbeaver.io/download/?start&os=win&arch=x86_64).

You select the view and then right-click -> Generate SQL -> DDL

Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I could suggest you to try [Backup tool](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/mysql-backup.html#header) in dbForge Studio for MySQL. You can use trial or free express edition, which allows creating sql-scripts up to 1MB, I think it will be enough for all views definitions.

So, there are some simple steps:

1. Choose database in objects tree and run Backup command.
2. Select objects to backup (views only).
3. Check 'Exclude DEFINER and SQL SECURITY clauses' option, and click Buckup button.